# Como somar variáveis de maneira correta?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma série de checkboxes onde o usuário deve selecionar várias opções e cada opção incrementa uma ou mais variáveis.

```
// Variáveis das características citopáticas 

var hipercromasia = document.getElementById("hipercromasia");
var cromatina_grosseira = document.getElementById("cromatina_grosseira");
var queratinizacao = document.getElementById("queratinizacao");
var cariomegalia = document.getElementById("cariomegalia");
var binucleacao = document.getElementById("binucleacao");
var coilocito = document.getElementById("coilocito");

// Variáveis que armazenam os checkboxes selecionados

var ASCUS = [];
var ASCH = [];
var LSIL = [];
var HSIL = [];

// Verifica os critérios citológicos

if (hipercromasia.checked) {
  ASCUS++;
  ASCH++;  
} 
if (cromatina_grosseira.checked) {
  HSIL++;
}
if (queratinizacao.checked) {
  LSIL++;
  HSIL++;   
}
if (cariomegalia.checked) {
  HSIL++;
  ASCUS++;  
}
if (binucleacao.checked) {
  HSIL++;
  ASCH++; 
}
 if (coilocito.checked) {
   ASCUS++;
   LSIL++;   
} 

 alert(ASCUS + ASCH + LSIL + HSIL);
```

O problema ocorre quando eu tento somar o resultado das variáveis pra posteriormente fazer a porcentagem e etc.

Por exemplo: 
Se eu selecionar "Hipercromasia" e "Cromatina_grosseira", ele me retorna 21, e não 3.

Como devo fazer a soma dessas variáveis?

Comment: Por que suas variáveis são vetores inicialmente? Por que não 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deves iniciar esses contadores com `0` e não com `[]`.
Falta também a lógica para diminuir esses valores se uma checkbox for desmarcada. Se tiveres uma função que corre sempre que precisares, essa lógico pode ser omitida.

Uma sugestão seria fazer isso assim:

```js
// Variáveis das características citopáticas 
var hipercromasia = document.getElementById("hipercromasia");
var cromatina_grosseira = document.getElementById("cromatina_grosseira");
var queratinizacao = document.getElementById("queratinizacao");
var cariomegalia = document.getElementById("cariomegalia");
var binucleacao = document.getElementById("binucleacao");
var coilocito = document.getElementById("coilocito");

function somar() {
  // Variáveis que armazenam os checkboxes selecionados
  var ASCUS = 0;
  var ASCH = 0;
  var LSIL = 0;
  var HSIL = 0;

  // Verifica os critérios citológicos
  if (hipercromasia.checked) {
    ASCUS++;
    ASCH++;
  }
  if (cromatina_grosseira.checked) {
    HSIL++;
  }
  if (queratinizacao.checked) {
    LSIL++;
    HSIL++;
  }
  if (cariomegalia.checked) {
    HSIL++;
    ASCUS++;
  }
  if (binucleacao.checked) {
    HSIL++;
    ASCH++;
  }
  if (coilocito.checked) {
    ASCUS++;
    LSIL++;
  }
  return ASCUS + ASCH + LSIL + HSIL;
}

var soma = somar();
console.log(soma);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, era exatamente o que estava precisando, muito obrigado!

Comment: Prezado, o Math.abs() retorna 0 quando o valor for null e retorna um número quando o valor for uma string ([documentação MDN[(https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)). Portanto, minha resposta era válida. Eu apenas me ative no escopo do problema exposto pelo autor da pergunta, no qual ele informa que o problema era "em vez de somar 2+1 = 3, estava retornando 2+1 = 21". Pelo conteúdo da pergunta, entendi que era essa a única dúvida, e em nenhum momento ele deixou claro que necessitava de um código completo.

Comment: ...Sua resposta, embora tenha solucionado o problema (assim como a minha), não me agradou por fugir, ao meu ver, do escopo da pergunta. É como se a pessoa dissesse "não consigo abrir meu carro com essa chave", e vc forneceu um carro completo pra pessoa.

Comment: @Dvdsamm obrigado por esclareceres! A meu ver o problema é estar a declarar contadores que começam em zero e vão somando com `[]`. Esse é o problema da lógica e a minha única alteração ao código do AP. Daí a minha primeira linha `Deves iniciar esses contadores com 0 e não com [].`. O que fiz depois foi encapsular o código com a correção descrita em cima numa função. Não mudei mais nada.